# Not able to click element via webdriver selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to run the following, but I keep getting element not visible message

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://ossc.ca/player-home-and-dashboard/day-to-day-info/schedules/4597")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("user_password").click()
```

I tried to dig into the web page html, and I can see the following:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="">
<table class="form">
<tbody></tbody></table></form>
```

If enctype blocking me from clicking on the element?

I tried looking up on web was not able to find anything, Any help or idea will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `input` elements with the same `id` attribute `"user_password"` on page: the first one is hidden. You can use index to choose visible one:

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("user_password")[1].click()
```

or you can use more specific selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td.element>input#user_password").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//PATH").click()
```

Exemple of a Path : //html/body/div/a